# awk approach to subset file based on three columns

Tags: awk, subset

I have a file in .BED format (input.bed)

```
less input.bed
A     678     934     0bb6fdb5    0       +
A     715     986     8bc17666    0       +
A     716     1029    065f9d32    0       -
A     769     1367    572ae096    0       +
B     801     924     e6f469bf    0       +
B     876     1007    384622c7    0       +
B     921     1118    9f8bdbbb    0       -
C     1038    1841    f9a29a0g    0       +
C     1078    1929    9cd655be    0       +
```

I want to subset the file from the LINUX command line and produce a new file that contains all lines with "A" in the first column, a value larger than 715 in the second column, and a value smaller than 1367 in the third column.

I tried using awk

```
awk -F '$1 == "A" && $2 >= 715 && $3 <= 1367' input.bed > output.bed
```

But I get the error message:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: input.bed
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ syntax error
```

The desired output looks like this

```
less output.bed
A     715     986     8bc17666    0       +
A     716     1029    065f9d32    0       -
A     769     1367    572ae096    0       +
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try following, with your shown samples. Assuming that your Input_file is space delimited then we need not to use space delimiter since that's default one for `awk`(in your attempted code no value is set for field separator is causing issues). In case you have tab as field separator then change `awk` to `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` in following code.

```
awk '$1=="A" && $2>=715 && $3<=1367' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, checking 2 conditions if 1st field is A, 2nd field is greater than or equals to 715 AND 3rd field is lesser than or equals to 1367 then print that line. Once you are happy with above code(which will print lines on terminal) then append  `>  output.bed` to get output file from program.

***NOTE:*** For OP's statement:

> a value larger than 715 in the second column, and a value smaller than
> 1367 in the third column.

In case we don't want to include 715 and 1367 values then change conditions to:

```
awk '$1=="A" && $2>715 && $3<1367' Input_file
```

Comment: This works well, thanks! But why did I get an error message with my one-liner code? You removed the gaps between the mathematical operators and you removed the "-F" argument, correct?

Comment: @AennaPhD, yes as mentioned in solution, default field separator is space and you need not to set it, your syntax is also not correct there, that's what fixed in it.

Comment: what do you mean with "syntax is also not correct there"? Thanks!

Comment: @AennaPhD, you can give field separator as for example: `-F'\t'` (make tab as field separator) or `-F'abc'`(make abc as field separator) to make field separators for whole file.