# R read specific items from unformatted text with condition

Tags: r, text, import

I have been using SAS for many years but now I have to transition into R. I really tried to search the net for this specific need but was unsuccessful.

I have the following huge file of which I will display the first two rows only (note each line contains up to 201 characters)

```
3 0B  1031001J13JUN2219JUN22   4    OTP07000700+0300  MAD10001000+02000 737IBCDPOMAYU                                           0B                0 S            M                              00000001
4 0B  1031001J              AB010OTPMADW2 9322                                                                                                                                                    000002
```

First, I need to import specific data from this file **but** only if the first position of each row starts with "3".

If the first position is a 3, I need to import the following data:

Company code (position 3-5),
flight_number (position 6-9) formatted as a character,
Origin (position 37-39),
Destination (position 55-57),
Days_of_operation (position 29-35) formatted as character.

Would appreciate your advice on how to do this.

Comment: Would you `dput(head(your_data))` ?

Comment: Is `3 OB...` a row, and `4 OB...` a next row terminated by `\n`, which is just asking if `3` rows are on their own line in the imported file?

Comment: You'll likely want to read `?readr:read_fwf` are you're looking at fixed width data. The question then is whether to import all data, then toss all non-3 data, or perl that out prior then import remainder.

Comment: That data does not look "unformatted".  You seem to know exactly how it is formatted.

Comment: I've found conditional file reading in R to be rather troublesome, and perhaps the sign of an unhealthy workflow, as files are not databases. I would create another file, then manipulate as needed in R. For example via `awk`, one could do `awk '$1 == 3' yourfile.txt > filetouseinR.txt` (or [more specific subsetting criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705592/awk-approach-to-subset-file-based-on-three-columns)), then proceed as normal in R.

Comment: I apologize if I used "un-formatted", probably wrong description. Maybe data that is not separated by space or tab might be a better description.  The data sometimes has multiple lines that start with 4, it is not always one "3" followed by 1 "4". Sometimes there are lines that start with "1" or "5" as well, and those are not needed as well.  The file is huge (over 3.5 GB) so making a copy probably is not the best way to do it.

Comment: With SAS it was quit simple, putting an if Statement in the read means that it will only read in anything that starts with "3" and then using the "@" to specify the position and the variable type eg) $2 to specify character count to read in.

Comment: I don't know R, but it looks like R should be able to do this easily.  Use the read.fwf() function so you can tell it where on the line the variables are.  And use pipe() function to let you call the operating system command grep to select only the lines that start with the digit 3 (something like   `grep ^3` ) to the read.fwf() function.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the full record specification available to you (your Company code (position 3-5) & etc above) it will be easier for you to define things, but using your data as presented:

```
fwf_record <- c('3 0B  1031001J13JUN2219JUN22   4    OTP07000700+0300  MAD10001000+02000 737IBCDPOMAYU                                           0B                0 S            M                              00000001','4 0B  1031001J              AB010OTPMADW2 9322                                                                                                                                                    000002')
```

note there are no `\n` line returns in this particular data, though likely in your file... This is important for playing around purposes as readr::read_fwf
expects `\n`, but in its absence wrapping in `I()` suffices... We have two records, what does readr::read_fwf make of our 1st record, without any other info as to field start/ends & etc

```
readr::read_fwf(I(fwf_record[1]))
                                                                                Rows: 1 Columns: 12                
── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

chr (9): X2, X3, X5, X6, X7, X8, X10, X11, X12
dbl (3): X1, X4, X9

ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
# A tibble: 1 × 12
     X1 X2    X3              X4 X5    X6    X7    X8       X9 X10   X11   X12  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>        <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     3 0B    1031001J13J…     4 OTP0… MAD1… 737I… 0B        0 S     M     0000…
```

As you provide more info from your record specification relative to start/end positions. If your read both records `readr::read_fwf(I(fwf_record)), you see that column specs are effectively reduced to what is most generalizable across all records and is likely not what you want.

```
readr::read_fwf(I(fwf_record))
                                                                                Rows: 2 Columns: 10                
── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

chr (8): X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X8, X9, X10
dbl (2): X1, X7

ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
# A tibble: 2 × 10
     X1 X2    X3                       X4    X5    X6       X7 X8    X9    X10  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>                    <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     3 0B    1031001J13JUN2219JUN22 … MAD1… 737I… 0B        0 S     M     0000…
2     4 0B    1031001J              A… NA    NA    NA       NA NA    NA    0000…
```

In your position, people want you to work effectively with the available data, it is also likely that the full record specification is also available. From ?readr::read_fwf examples note:

## 3. Paired vectors of start and end positions

```
 read_fwf(fwf_sample, fwf_positions(c(1, 30), c(20, 42), c("name", "ssn")))
```

So I would wrestle the 'how to read this thing' to the ground first, then address the next steps of selecting only useful records & etc, to translate your prior SAS workflow to R. As separate questions as need be...